# NoClassfoundDefError : OWLOntologyCreationException from executing swing jar file

Tags: java, swing, maven, owl-api

I am developing a Java Swing application using Maven, and I have added `net.sourceforge.owlapi` version 5.1.0

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>owlapi-distribution</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

There is no problem at all if I run the application from Netbeans, but when I run it from the `jar` generated from the build and triggering a listener that calls `loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument` method, I found in console `noclassdeffounderror : OWLOntologyCreationException`.

Here is the method when I am calling :

```
        try {
            File file = new File(baseUrl.split("///")[1] + suffixUrl);

            if (file == null) {
                return;
            } else {
                System.out.println("file is null " + file.getAbsolutePath());

            }
            OWLOntology ontology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(file);

            OWLDataFactory factory = manager.getOWLDataFactory();

            ...

            } catch (OWLOntologyCreationException | OWLOntologyStorageException ex) {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
            }
```

The method `loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument` throws `OWLOntologyCreationException`

My build in `pom.xml` :

```
        º<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>ui.AppFrame</mainClass>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

[UPDATE]
Error trace :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDsT0.png)

[UPDATE2]
assembly.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assembly> 
    <id>full</id>  
    <formats> 
        <format>zip</format> 
    </formats>
    <dependencySets> 
        <dependencySet> 
            <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact> 
            <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory> 
        </dependencySet> 
    </dependencySets> 

    <fileSets> 
        <fileSet> 
            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory> 
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory> 
            <includes> 
                <include>*.jar</include> 
            </includes> 
        </fileSet> 

        <fileSet> 
            <directory>data</directory> 
            <outputDirectory>/data</outputDirectory> 
            <includes> 
                <include>*</include> 
            </includes> 
        </fileSet>

        <fileSet> 
            <directory>data/projects</directory> 
            <outputDirectory>/data/projects</outputDirectory> 
            <includes> 
                <include>*</include> 
            </includes> 
        </fileSet> 
        <fileSet> 
            <directory>data/onto</directory> 
            <outputDirectory>/data/onto</outputDirectory> 
            <includes> 
                <include>*</include> 
            </includes> 
        </fileSet> 
        <fileSet> 
            <directory>data/onto/core</directory> 
            <outputDirectory>/data/onto/core</outputDirectory> 
            <includes> 
                <include>*</include> 
            </includes> 
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet> 
            <directory>data/onto/obs</directory> 
            <outputDirectory>/data/onto/obs</outputDirectory> 
            <includes> 
                <include>*</include> 
            </includes> 
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet> 
            <directory>data/onto/extern</directory> 
            <outputDirectory>/data/onto/extern</outputDirectory> 
            <includes> 
                <include>*</include> 
            </includes> 
        </fileSet>

        <fileSet> 
            <directory>data/onto/tech</directory> 
            <outputDirectory>/data/onto/tech</outputDirectory> 
            <includes> 
                <include>*</include> 
            </includes> 
        </fileSet> 
     </fileSets> 
</assembly>
```

Comment: Please paste the full stack trace of the exception in the question.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have just uploaded the trace

Comment: I suspect you need a maven assembly tag on the question, because I believe the assembly is leaving the OWLAPI jars out of your artifact or some information is missing from its metadata. However I'm no expert so can't tell for sure. As a starter, check that the artifact includes the OWLAPI jars (and its recursive dependencies).

Comment: Thank you, I have just updated the question putting the assembly.xml code